# angularjs localStorage prevent duplicate data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I do not know how can i prevent duplicate string (the value that push to array document can be same if it same i need display error) using localStorage

My Controller

```
      .controller('NewCtrl', function($scope, ConstSearch, SaveDocuments) {                                 
          $scope.saveDocument = function (documents) {                                                      
              //Create new project                                                                          
              $scope.document = [{"id": 1, "name": "New", "link": "#/new"}];                    
              SaveDocuments.save($scope.document[0].id,$scope.document[0].name,$scope.document[0].link);    
          };                                                                                                
}
```

My services

```
 .factory('SaveDocuments', function() {
            var documents = [];
            return {
                save: function (id, name, link) {
                    for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
                        key = localStorage.key(i);
                        value = localStorage.getItem(key);
//How can i access documents.id that already add??
                        console.log(value);
                        break;
                    } // end for loop

                    // add to it,
                    documents.push({id: id, name: name, link: link});
                    // then put it back.
                    localStorage.setItem('document', JSON.stringify(documents));
                },
            }

    });
```

Comment: `if(documents.filter(function(a){return a.id==id}).length){ alert('conflict!'); }` newer browsers can use [].find() instead which would be faster if there were 100+ documents.